# Get details of the selected item of spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a data in JSON format which consists of city id and names. when an item is selected i want its cityid. I tried doing this. but itdoes not show correct cityid.

```
    JSONArray gg = new JSONArray(objCity);
                ArrayList<String> cityal = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> cityalid = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j=0; j<gg.length(); j++){
                    pojo = new Pojo();
                    JSONObject jobj = gg.getJSONObject(j);
                    String cityid = jobj.optString("id");
                    String cityName = jobj.optString("name");
                    cityal.add(cityName);
                    cityalid.add(cityid);
                }

                List<String> listTem = cityal;
                List<String> listTemId = cityalid;

                Set<String> tem = new HashSet<String>(listTem);
                Set<String> temid = new HashSet<String>(listTemId);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editr = getSharedPreferences("City", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                tem.addAll(listTem);
                temid.addAll(listTemId);
                editr.putStringSet("cityname", tem);
                editr.putStringSet("cityid", temid);
                editr.commit();
```

and in postExecute

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Post exec calleld", "dfds");
        nDialog.dismiss();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("City", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("cityname", null);
        Set<String> set11 = prefs.getStringSet("cityid", null);

        List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        titlesList.addAll(set);

        List<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        descList.addAll(set11);

        ssservice.clear();
        for (String p : set) {
            pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.setCityName(p);
            al_city.add(pojo);
            ssservice.add(p);
        }
        for (String p11 : set11) {
            pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.setCityId(p11);
            al_cityId.add(pojo);
            ssservice11.add(p11);
        }

        Log.e("Cityname",""+al_city);
        Log.e("City iddd", ""+al_cityId);

        spinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                ssservice));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        spinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ed_spinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String idd = pojo.getCityId();
                        Log.e("City id from spinner",""+idd);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        // set dialog message

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select City");
        // alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // create alert dialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        final Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.c_spinner);
        //mSpinner.setAdapter(ssservice);
        mSpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        ssservice));
        final Button mButton = (Button) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.c_btn);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos= mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Log.e("POS",""+pos);
                pojo = new Pojo();
                String cid = al_cityId.get(pos).getCityId();
                Log.e("ciddddd",""+cid);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                        "CityIdSpinner", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                editor.putString("id", cid);
            }
        });

        // reference UI elements from my_dialog_layout in similar fashion

        //  mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        return;
    }
```

This is my jsom

```
[{"city":[{"id":"3","name":"Pune"},{"id":"4","name":"Bhopal"},{"id":"5","name":"Indore"},{"id":"6","name":"Amravati"},{"id":"8","name":"Wardha"},{"id":"12","name":"Nagpur"},{"id":"16","name":"akola"}]
```

Please suggest me something.

Comment: What type of error you are getting?

Comment: @Amy I am not getting any error. cityId is not correct

Comment: Where is your ItemClickListener?

Comment: @Amy  mButton.setOnClickListener

Comment: Your question in incomplete please post JSON string and whole code of the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97402/discussion-between-amy-and-priyanka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your values in HashMap. cityname as Key and ID as value.

```
        HashMap<String,String> spinnerValuesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++){
          JSONObject jobj = gg.getJSONObject(j);
          String cityid = jobj.optString("id");
          String cityName = jobj.optString("name")
          spinnerValuesMap.put(cityName,cityid);
         }
```

Access Id Like This:

```
String selectedItem= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String cityId = spinnerValuesMap.get(selectedItem);  // Your CIty id is here
```